# Call a method of dll

Tags: installshield

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with the `InstallShield`, Is it possible to call a method of asp.net assembly(dll) in the `InstallShield`? If it can be, please kindly give me some sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Which edition and version of InstallShield are you asking about? It's possible to call methods in managed assemblies in some editions/versions.

Comment: @MichaelUrman InstallShield2011 or higher version, thanks.